# Synaptics (synclient) no longer loads

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
Desktop:        Gnome v3.20
Computer:       Samsung Ativ Book 8
```

About a week ago, I started getting this error message when trying to run a synclient command for my touchpad:

> Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?

My touchpad actually works (regular mouse functionality, 2 finger scrolling, etc) - I just can't change any of it's settings using `synclient`
I've run these commands several times:

```
sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Those commands run as expected and it appears I have synaptics installed. But I get the same error message any time I try to access the `synclient` command.

This really seems like it should have a simple solution. Is there something I can check to see if the right files are being loaded in my path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like Gnome 3.20 replaces synaptics with libinput (see [this archlinux link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=211112) for more info).