# Is there a way to have a right edge scroll function on Ubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, mouse, touchpad, 17.10, budgie

This was a feature I had on an older xp machine where if I dragged my finger on the right edge of my trackpad it would move down the page.  Since Ubuntu is now way ahead of xp, I would assume there is a way to enable a feature like this.  If this is possible, how?  Thanks and regards,
Thomas

Comment: Should be enabled by default. There is also a setting for it under Mouse and Touchpad.

Comment: This is why I commented, All I got was the option of the primary button, the mouse speed, and the natural scrolling.

Comment: Why haven't you mentioned it in the question?

Comment: I assumed it to be implied, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This command works on Ubuntu 14.04. I'm not sure about Budgie 17.10.

```
synclient VertEdgeScroll=1
```

To disable:

```
synclient VertEdgeScroll=0
```

Comment: It gives me this error:    Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?

Comment: @TomHancock Yeah, sorry, looks like synaptics has been replaced by libinput on Gnome. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/781500/301745).

Comment: So is there a replacement command?

Comment: @TomHancock Doesn't look like it, no. If you google "libinput edge scrolling", you'll find all sorts of posts saying it's been deprecated. The reasoning is explained here: [Why libinput doesn't support edge scrolling](http://who-t.blogspot.ca/2015/03/why-libinput-doesnt-support-edge.html)